# Add/remove eventListeners while keeping instance context of "this"

Tags: javascript, events, callback, this

I am trying to use the vanilla JS event system to send events between different components of my browser application (no NodeJS involved), by dispatching events to the `window` object.

```js
// method in Class A
sendDone() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('done');
}
```

In another class, I have a method which handles the *optional* listener to this event, which can be enabled/disabled by the user.

```js
// method in Class B
setOption(shouldListen) {
  if (shouldListen) {
    window.addEventListener('done', this.doneHandler);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('done', this.doneHandler);
  }
}
```

However, the handler gets the `window` context instead of the instance context, and the `this` keyword doesn't work as I would like it to:

```js
// method in Class B
doneHandler() {
  this.someMethod(this.someValue);  // doesn't work
}
```

I can't pass `this` to the handler with an anonymous function, because I can't remove an anonymous function from the listeners list. For the same reason, I can't include the handler code inside the function definition, like this:

```js
const self = this;
window.addEventListener('done', function() {
  // can use self here instead
  // but listener still can't be removed
});
```

I'm new to JS and I'm wondering how this sort of scenario is usually handled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) in the constructor of your class:

```
constructor() {
    this.doneHandler = this.doneHandler.bind(this);
}
```

The rest of the code won't change, so now you can add and remove the event listener.